# bufsize must be an integer error while grepping a message

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running into following error while trying to grep for  a message consisting of multipe lines in a log...can anyone provide inputs on how to overcome this error?

CODE:-

```
    print gerrit_commitmsg
    gerritlog = Popen('git','log','--grep','gerrit_commitmsg', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    print gerritlog
```

ERROR:-

```
Commit message:-

Build system changes

Build system changes to include packages in the build

Change-Id: I697558f01ae367d2baacdf2c7fcf1a03753edacd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gerrits_in_workspace.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "gerrits_in_workspace.py", line 77, in main
    grep_commitmsg(gerrit_commitmsg)
  File "gerrits_in_workspace.py", line 48, in grep_commitmsg
    gerritlog = Popen('git','log','--grep','gerrit_commitmsg', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 629, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `subprocess.Popen` class expects an argument list like this:

```
Popen(args, bufsize=0, ...)
```

So you're passing it:

- `args` = `git`
- `bufsize` = `log`

Hence the error (`bufsize` expects an integer value).  The command vector needs to be a list, like this:

```
gerritlog = Popen(['git','log','--grep','gerrit_commitmsg'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: thanks,also i want to grep for what is in gerrit_commitmsg but not the string gerrit_commitmsg itself,any tips on how can we do it?

Comment: That's a different question, and you're best bet is probably to post a new question here on SO.