# Python + Windows: subprocess and bufsize

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program, which perfectly runs on Linux but - what an miracle- not an Windows.
I already fix one bug with sys, and get a new one :

```
"TypeError: bufsize must be an integer"
```

I am pretty sure it is something very easy I forgot to try- any hints? Thanks!

```
import subprocess
import sys
process = subprocess.Popen(sys.executable, [player["progname"]], 
          stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  
          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
          universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bufsize must be an integer error while grepping a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824096/bufsize-must-be-an-integer-error-while-grepping-a-message)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to wrap both `sys.executable` and `player["progname"]` in a `list`.

```
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, player["progname"]], 
          ...)
```

Otherwise, you're passing `player["progname"]` as the `bufsize` argument to the Popen constructor (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Comment: Thank you so much - it works ... you are totally right I have to include sys.executable!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of Popen constructor should be an integer and you are passing `[player["progname"]]`