# How to write top output to a file in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to write top -n1 to a file in python. It is giving a buffer size error. I'm new to python, and don't understand this as it looks pretty straight forward.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("top", "n1",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
topfile = open("top.txt","w+")
topFile.write(output)
topFile.close()
```

Error:

> p = subprocess.Popen("top", "n1",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
>
> File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
>   line 659, in **init**
>       raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer") TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Adding in buffsize as int

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("top", "n1",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, bufsize =1)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
topHeavyFile = open("topHeavy.txt","w+")
topHeavyFile.write(output)
topHeavyFile.close()
```

Error:

> p = subprocess.Popen("top", "n1",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False,
>   bufsize =1) TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for keyword
>   argument 'bufsize'

Comment: You need to pass `subprocess.Popen(["top", "n1"], stdout .. )` instead of just `("top", "n1" ..`.

Comment: It's giving me a top error now so that's better. top -n1 is a valid top command but it is throwing a top error. I'm guessing I need to push an array of arguments, but how does top -n1 work from CLI but in this case it throws a top error. If I push the "-n1" into the array it hangs.

Comment: I just did, it hangs which is weird. I wonder if there is a problem with p.communicate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824096/bufsize-must-be-an-integer-error-while-grepping-a-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["top", "n1", "b"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
```

The `"b"` which stands for batch mode solves the `top: failed tty get` error.